# Vanishing of higher limits

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, limits-and-colimits, abelian-categories, derived-functors

Let $I$ be a directed set and let $X_I$ be a corresponding inverse system of, say, (complex) vector spaces or abelian groups (in my case in general not finite-dimensional, resp. not finitely generated).

If (the cofinality of) $I$ is the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, then the Mittag-Leffler condition ensures the vanishing of the $\lim^1$-term and also of all higher lim-terms. In general, only the *sufficiently high* lim-terms $\lim^n X_I$ vanish (how high depends on the cofinality of $I$).

Now in my case, I have the directed set $\mathbb{N}^J$ for an infinite set $J$, where the order is defined as $f \le g$ if and only if $f(j) \le g(j)$ for all $j \in J$. The cofinality of this is larger than $\mathbb{N}$ but do we maybe still have that the Mittag-Leffler condition implies vanishing of all higher lim-terms (including the $\lim^1$)? In my case, the connecting maps of the inverse system are even split surjective (which is a stronger condition than what Mittag-Leffler needs).

Comment: Under what conditions do sufficiently high $\varprojlim^n$ terms vanish? I believe that if the cofinality of $I$ is $\aleph_n$, then $\varprojlim^{\geq n+2} X = 0$, but I believe that if the cofinality of $I$ is $\geq \aleph_{\omega+1}$, then $\varprojlim^n X$ can be nonvanishing for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following comment of Dustin Clausen answers my question negatively: [Example of an uncountable sequence of abelian groups with nonvanishing $\varprojlim^2$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377274/example-of-an-uncountable-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-nonvanishing-varproj?rq=1#comment957027_377274)